# AJAX script not returning success in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

JS:

```
$(function() {
    load_custom_topics()
//    load_main()
});

function load_custom_topics(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: 'http://rickymason.net/thebump/index.php/ajax/load_custom_topics',
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: { },
        success: function(page){
            alert(page);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

load_custom_topics

```
public function load_custom_topics()
{
    $check = $this->page_model->check_active_topic();
    if ($check == FALSE) 
    {
            $page['content'] = 'TEST equals FALSE'; 
    } else {
            $page['content'] = 'TRUE'; 
    }
    echo json_encode($page);
}
```

going to the page index.php/ajax/load_custom_topics returns this:

`{"content":"TEST equals FALSE"}`

The alert is not firing! Any idea why?

Comment: Because you do not load any view in your controller, just echo'ing `$page` array

Comment: hm, i didnt know it was required to load a view...let me try that, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, on inspecting a request to your controller, I found that you weren't setting the proper headers the ajax call expects (text/json).

See codeigniter's [Output](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html) class.

Using

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($page));
```

instead of

```
echo json_encode($page);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I added a view like the above poster suggested, and changed the echo to the code you provided, and still am not getting an alert. I should point out that I see the JS running, and putting an alert prior to the ajax function allows the alert to go off.

Comment: get rid of view. IMO you don't need one.